# Is using Option#get really a bad idea here?

Tags: functional-programming, exceptions, scala

I'm working on a Scala project and Wartremover shows an error about `Option#get` usage in my code:

```
Option#get is disabled - use Option#fold instead
```

While I do understand how `get` should often be avoided, I think there are cases where it's reasonable to use it, like my current one: First, I create an answer item (in the database), then I want to return the freshly created answer by reading it from there.

```scala
def create(answer: Answer): Future[Answer] = {
  writeToDb(answer) // returns Future[Long]
    .flatMap(
      readFromDb(_) // returns Future[Option[Answer]]
        .map(_.get) // Wartremover complains here
    )
}
```

My understanding is that `get` should generally be avoided because it breaks control flow in case of `None`, as an exception is thrown.
However, I expect my `Option` here to always contain an answer, as I just created it.
If it's not there, there's likely a bug in my code or an issue with the database.
In such a case it would be unreasonable to fall back to a default value or `null`. I'd much rather throw an exception or directly map to a failing future.

An alternative to `get` is explicitly matching agains the option:

```scala
def create(answer: Answer): Future[Answer] = {
  writeToDb(answer) // returns Future[Long]
    .flatMap(
      readFromDb(_) // returns Future[Option[Answer]]
        .flatMap {
          case Some(answer) => Future.successful(answer)
          case None => Future.failed(
            new IllegalStateException("Failed to load answer after creation"))
        }
    )
}
```

But this is way more verbose while achieving almost the same as a simple `_.get`.

Am I missing something here? Or is this just a false positive from Wartremover?

Comment: This sounds to me like a question that would be better asked on Stack Overflow. However, I know next to nothing about Scala, so ignore me if this is not the case.

Comment: Why do you even need to re-read from the database? Getting a generated ID?

Comment: @DavidArno It's about best practices with regard to functional programming, so I thought it fits best here.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes, exactly. The initial answer before saving is therefore incomplete, plus reading from the db also ensures consistency between what is stored and what will be returned.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach But unless this whole function is in an isolated transaction, your query could, in fact, return null. There's a race condition with another process deleting the entry immediately after it was added.

Comment: @SebastianRedl That's true, but it's something that should never happen during normal execution. Why should another thread try to delete an answer I've just created (short of buggy behavior)? That's why I would like to return a failing future (or throw an exception) in such a case.

Comment: You get the benefit of a specific exception with the initial `answer` as context, rather than a general exception of "get on an empty `Option[Answer]`"

Comment: @CedricReichenbach One use case scenario I could think of would be a anti-spam bot that automatically check answers as they are added to the database and immediately deletes them if it thinks they're spam.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Okay, fair enough. But still, from the outside this would be a failure in user creation, therefore ideally a failed future.

Comment: You could avoid this entirely by making your db insert do `RETURNING ...`, assuming postgres

Comment: Why does your DB function return an `Option[Answer]` if you *know* there must always be an `Answer`? Don't you have a function that just returns `Answer`? (i.e. don't you have a DB function that returns `T` instead of `Option[T]`?)

Comment: @AndresF. I know it in this case because previous actions, but the db access layer doesn't know. I.e. in other cases, an answer might not exist and the function therefore return `None`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of pattern matching explicitly, you can write

```
.getOrElse { throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load answer after creation") }
```

More generally, when dealing with `Option`/`Either`/`Try` you can often avoid pattern matching by looking for an existing method and reserve it for cases where you need to do something non-trivial.

I wouldn't really consider it a false positive: being explicit about the exception is good and will make it easier to find and add more debugging information if you do run into a problem.

Comment: Ok, I see the point about explicit exceptions. However, this will now get rejected by Wartremover because of the `Throw` rule, which forbids any throwing.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Wartremover rejects any throwing, or just throwing inside an `Option`?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach The motivation for this rule is "throw implies partiality. Encode exceptions/errors as return values instead using Either." and a failed future works fine for this. So it doesn't particularly apply.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I personally wouldn't enable `Throw` rule in the first place, but your mileage may vary (or you may be working on a project which already came to decision to enable it).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for the input; I just integrated Wartremover and defaulted to `Wart.unsafe` (all rules considered stable), but am now finding several ones I find not reasonable and will probably disable.

Comment: It's a good thing that the creators of `Option` thought ahead and added a get-or-else-throw-exception method already for convenience. That means you don't have to write it out every time you want to use it.